# How do I delete all OSPF settings on a router?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, ospf, cisco-commands

I'm using PacketTracer. I want to delete all OSPF settings on a router.

I used `clear ip ospf process` but after that when I do `show ip ospf` I can still see the process, its area and all interfaces of that area still exist.

I want to delete everything as if I had not tried to configure OSPF before (of course without completely erasing the router configuration, e.g. I don't want to lose my interface IP configurations).

Comment: “Clear ip ospf <process>” resets and restarts the ospf process, but does not change the configuration. It is used in troubleshooting and if you want the router-id to update based on changed configuration. Clear ip ospf <process> can be impacting in production because it resets all neighbors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `no router ospf <process number>`?

That will delete the OSPF process. If you have created any interface specific OSPF configurations, you will need to deal with those individually.

Answer (score -2):

or if you want to remove all routing

no ip routing

then re-enable it

ip routing

Comment: That will not actually remove the OSPF, or any other routing configuration, so when you enable routing again, it is back to where it was.